# Equation with vertical arrow

Tags: equations, arrows

How I get this equation with vertical arrows that help describe some of its terms?

```
\begin{equation*}
0 \leq F = \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \overline{y})^2}_{(n-1)s_y^2} 
- 2b \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y})}_{(n-1)s_{xy} = (n-1)rs_xs_y}
+b^2 \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})^2}_{(n-1)s_x^2}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please make your code snippet complete and than extend it to small document with your equation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The command `\uparrow` makes an extensible arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\vertarrowbox[3][6ex]{%
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}} #2 \\
  \left\uparrow\vcenter{\hrule height #1}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\\
  \makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize#3}
  \end{array}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
0 \leq F = 
{\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})^2}_{(n-1)s_y^2}}
-\vertarrowbox{2b}{text}
{\underbrace{{}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}_{(n-1)s_{xy} = (n-1)rs_xs_y}}
+\vertarrowbox{b^2}{More text}
{\underbrace{{}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}_{(n-1)s_x^2}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
0 \leq F = 
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})^2
-2b
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})
+b^2
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The strange braces can be easily explained: `\underbrace` makes an Op atom, which conflicts with the spacing of binary operations, so it's best to brace it. However, if `\sum` is preceded by an ordinary symbol, a thin space should appear, which is produced by the empty subformula `{}` inside `\underbrace` when necessary.

The second display shows the standard spacing without `\underbrace` and the arrows, just for checking the spaces are the same.

The `\vertarrowbox` has an optional argument for the desired height of the arrow, default 6ex. Call it as `\vertarrowbox[12ex]{<symbol>}{<text>}` if you want to double the height (its size should depend on context).

[image]

Comment: I didn't aware, until I saw your solution, of the fact that `\uparrow` is extensible and thus can be resized using the `\left` and `\right` machinery. Good stuff!

Comment: Can this be used to describe an exponent somehow? Such as `e^{-\vertarrowbox{\lambda}{Some text}t}`. Without any changes this moves up the exponent instead of moving down the text

Comment: @blenderfreaky If it's not the only description, then `e^{-\smash{\!\vertarrowbox{\scriptstyle\lambda}{Some text}\!}t}` should do.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this? Observe that the solution sets a macro called `\vertarrowbox`, which takes two arguments: (a) the stuff to be placed on the main line of the equation, and (b) the text to be placed below the long vertical arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,graphicx}
\newcommand\vertarrowbox[2]{%
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \\
    \rotatebox{90}{$\xrightarrow{\hphantom{abcdefgh}}$} \\[-1ex]
    \mathclap{\scriptstyle\text{#2}}%
    \end{array}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
0 \leq F = 
\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})^2}%
       _{(n-1)s_y^2}  
{}-{}\vertarrowbox{2b}{text}
\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}%
       _{(n-1)s_{xy} = (n-1)rs_xs_y} 
{}+{}\vertarrowbox{b^2}{More text}
\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}%
       _{(n-1)s_x^2}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what a competition! you overtook me for 12 seconds. i obviously need a new, faster PC :-). +1 for nice answer

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks!! I've upvoted your answer in the meantime too. :-)

Comment: To the OP: Note that I've also replaced all instances of `\overline` with `\bar`.

Comment: `\phantom{\smash{...}}`? Why not `\hphantom`? But rotating is just wrong. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg - Good observation about replacing `\phantom{\smash{...}}` with `\hphantom{...}` `;-)`

Answer (score 8):

one possibilities is use of the package `tikz` and its  `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[11]
\[
0 \leq F =  \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \overline{y})^2}_{(n-1)s_y^2}
            - \tikzmark{A}2b
            \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y})}_{(n-1)s_{xy} = (n-1)rs_xs_y}
            + \tikzmark{B}b^2
            \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})^2}_{(n-1)s_x^2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,shorten <=1mm,font=\footnotesize]
\draw[<-] ([xshift=1.0ex] pic cs:A) -- ++ (0,-1.2) node[below] {text};
\draw[<-] ([xshift=0.5ex] pic cs:B) -- ++ (0,-1.2) node[below] {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip
\]
\lipsum*[12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Purely aesthetically, I think it's desirable to typeset the explanatory text blocks with `\footnotesize` or even `\scriptsize`.

Comment: @Mico, thank you for suggestion. corrected now.

Answer (score 5):

A short code with `pstricks` and `auto-pst-pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\begin{equation*}
0 \leq F = \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \overline{y})^2}_{(n-1)s_y^2}
{}-\rnode{B}{2b} \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y})}_{(n-1)s_{xy} = (n-1)rs_xs_y}
{}+\rnode{b2}{b^2} \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})^2}_{(n-1)s_x^2}
 \end{equation*}
 \psset{arrowinset=0.12, arrows=->, nodesep=4pt}
\uput{12ex}[d](B){\rnode[t]{T1}{\textsf{Text}}}\ncline{T1}{B}
\uput{12ex}[d](b2){\rnode[t]{T2}{\textsf{Text}}}\ncline{T2}{b2}
 \end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. To make the `-` and `+` terms between the summands act like binary rather than as unary operators, I think it's a good idea to surround them with pairs of curly braces, i.e., to write them as `{}-{}` and `{}+{}`, resp. Also, the three `\limits` directives aren't needed.

Comment: @Mico: One pair of braces for each node will do. Actually, it has nothing to do with the pstricks nodes (never noticed it previously): it seems to come from the `\underbrace`s.

Comment: I only ever noticed the spacing issue after coming across a comment by @egreg on this topic, i.e., the presence of `\underbrace` directives....