# Equation with table below

Tags: equations, arrows, tikz-arrows

I want a table to show the process involved in integration by parts. Here is what I have (from [Equation with vertical arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449324/equation-with-vertical-arrow)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\vertarrowbox[3][6ex]{%
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}} #2 \\
  \left\uparrow\vcenter{\hrule height #1}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\\
  \makebox[0pt]{\normalsize#3}
  \end{array}%
 }
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \int x\exp(ax)\, dx\, &\vertarrowbox[8pt]{=}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    $u=x$ & $du=dx$ \\\hline
    $dv=\exp(ax)\,dx$ & $v=\displaystyle\frac{1}{a}\exp(ax)$\\\hline
\end{tabular}} \frac{x}{a}\exp(ax)-\frac{1}{a}\int\exp(ax)\, dx\\
&=\frac{1}{a}\exp(ax)\left(x-\frac{1}{a}\right)+c.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to align the vertical line of the table with the arrow, and also if possible change the arrow style (like -Latex style in tikz).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose this solution, using `mathtools`, `makebox` and `makecell`, with some manual adjustment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{makebox, array, makecell}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
\setcellgapes{2pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{align*}
 \int x\exp(ax)\, dx\, & = \frac{x}{a}\exp(ax)-\frac{1}{a}\int\exp(ax)\, dx\\
  & \makebox*{${}={}$}{$\uparrow$}\\[-0.5ex]
\MoveEqLeft[-0.2] \mathclap{\begin{array}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    u=x & du=dx \\\hline
    dv=\exp(ax)\,dx & v=\mfrac{1}{a}\exp(ax)\\\hline
\end{array}}\\
&=\frac{1}{a}\exp(ax)\biggl(x-\frac{1}{a}\biggr)+c.
\end{align*}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

[image]