# Add arrow and text above equation

Tags: equations, labels, arrays

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}=\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h},0}\left(X_{\textnormal{m}}, X_{\textnormal{s}}, z\right)+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h},1}\left(X_{\textnormal{m}},X_{\textnormal{s}}, z\right)+\epsilon^2\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h},2}\left(X_{\textnormal{m}},X_{\textnormal{s}}, z\right)+\cdots\,.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**Question:** How can I label epsilon?
I'd like to have an arrow (\downarrow) pointing to the equation with text below the arrow.

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449324/36296 , https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522517/annotate-math-equation-with-text-on-arrows-around-the-equation , https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539238/add-simple-pointed-annotations-to-equations-in-latex-as-a-ctan-package-improve , https://ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `\textnormal` here; instead, use `\mathrm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `\overset`, where the upper part is a zero width `tabular` in the appropriate size, namely, `\scriptsize`.

In case you have various annotations, you may need to help TeX in order to get them at the same vertical position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\annot}[2]{% #1 symbol to annotate, #2 = text
  \overset{%
    \makebox[0pt]{%
      \normalfont\scriptsize
      \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #2 \\ $\downarrow$ \end{tabular}%
    }%
  }{\mathstrut #1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}=
\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},0}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\annot{\epsilon}{interesting}\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},1}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\epsilon^2\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},2}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\dotsb.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}=
\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},0}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\annot{\epsilon\vphantom{\epsilon^2}}{interesting}
   \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},1}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\annot{\epsilon^2}{more interesting}
   \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},2}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\dotsb.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note the omission of the useless `\left` and `\right` tokens, but also `\dotsb` instead of `\cdots`.

[image]

You can modify the code to allow for both above and below annotation: below positioning is obtained with `\annot*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\annot}{smm}{%
  % if *, below, otherwise above
  % #2 = symbol to annotate
  % #3 = text
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \innerannot{\underset}{#2}{#3}{\textuparrow}%
  }{%
    \innerannot{\overset}{#2}{\textdownarrow}{#3}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innerannot}{mmmm}{%
  #1{% \overset or underset
     \makebox[0pt]{%
       \normalfont\scriptsize
       \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #4 \\ #3 \end{tabular}%
    }%
  }{\mathstrut #2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}=
\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},0}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\annot{\epsilon}{interesting}\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},1}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\epsilon^2\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},2}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\dotsb.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}=
\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},0}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\annot{\epsilon\vphantom{\epsilon^2}}{interesting}
   \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},1}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\annot{\epsilon^2}{more interesting}
   \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},2}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\dotsb.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}=
\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},0}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\annot{\epsilon}{interesting}
   \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},1}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\annot*{\epsilon^2}{more interesting}
   \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},2}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
  +\dotsb.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. Probably off-topic but can I use the same structure to label a second epsilon below the equation?

Comment: @Sylvia See last edit

Answer (score 5):

The following solution provides two user macros: `\explainabove` and `\explainbelow`. They employ `\overset` and `\underset`, respectively, which are macros provided by the `amsmath` package, as well as `\mathclap`, a macro provide by the `mathtools` package. (The `mathtools` package is a superset of the `amsmath` package.) That way, you can simply write `\explainabove{some text}{\epsilon}` and \explainbelow{more text}{\epsilon^2} to provide the desired annotations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathclap' macro; load 'amsmath' automatically

%% two new user macros
\newcommand\explainabove[2]{%
    \overset{\overset{\mathclap{\textnormal{#1}}}{\downarrow}}{#2\mathstrut}}
\newcommand\explainbelow[2]{%
    \underset{\underset{\mathclap{\textnormal{#1}}}{\uparrow}}{#2\mathstrut}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}
=\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},0}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}},z)
+\explainabove{some text}{\epsilon}
 \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},1}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}},z)
+\explainbelow{more text}{\epsilon^2}
 \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h},2}(X_{\mathrm{m}},X_{\mathrm{s}}, z)
+\dotsb
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd not use `\substack` but `\underset`.